# jqgrid: Disable submit button in add form

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have created an event handler for User id input box, based on which I need to disable/enable Submit button in jqgrid add form.
I tried to apply disable style class for this, button gets disabled but am unable to stop it from calling the event handler on click of that button.

```
{
    name: 'userId',
    label: 'User Id',
    index: 'userId',
    key: true,
    editable: true,
    edittype: "text",
    editrules: {
        required: true
    },
    editoptions: {
        size: 40,
        maxlength: 40,
        dataEvents: [{
            type: 'blur',
            fn: function (e) {
                var userIdVal = $("#userId").val().trim();
                if (userIdVal.length > 0) {
                    $("#sData").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                } else {
                    $("#sData").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                }
            }
        }]
    },
```

Is there a way to disable this button?

Comment: Guys, I tried many ways to fix this, none of them worked out. Am stuck with this issue. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the functions `.attr()` and `.removeAttr()`

```
$("#sData").attr("disabled","disabled"); // Disable button
$("#sData").removeAttr("disabled"); // Enable button
```

This way the events doesn't fire.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Fizk/8VfhY/1/ for an example.

Comment: I tried them, it didn't work out, since in jgrid Submit button is generated as link as:  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="sData" class="fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left">Submit<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span></a>